# OSGI component not activated after bundle activated

Tags: spring-boot, osgi

new to OSGI.

I use spring-boot in OSGI. In bundle activator, spring-boot application starts up successfully. I have a component class as below

```
@Service // spring-boot annotation
@Component(immediate = true) // osgi annotation
public class Test {
    @Activate
    public void activate() {
        System.out.println("osgi component activated");
    }

    @Reference
    public void set(ServiceComponentXXX a) {
        System.out.println("reference got");
}
```

The class Test only binds services and are not binded by any other. The class ServiceComponnetXXX is from other bundle. the activate and set methods are never executed.

After remove spring-boot annotation @Service, code works fine. so the question is that can a class be both a spring-boot component and an OSGI component?

Answer (score 4):

It does not really make sense to make a class be both. The lifecycles of spring boot and declarative services are completely separate. So in best case you end up with two instances of the class - One populated by spring boot and the other by declarative services - but it is a lot more likely that it just does not work.

I suggest to decide if you want to go OSGi. If yes then jut use declarative services and not spring boot. In general decide for one injection framework. In OSGi you can have one injection framework by bundle but they have to be OSGi compatible. Spring boot is not really OSGi compatible.

Comment: is there any solution for an OSGI component to use a spring-boot component in the same OSGI bundle or vice versa? the background is that 1)there is a traditional desktop app implemented with OSGI, 2)I need to provide a web interface for that app, 3)currently the solution is to embedded spring-boot into OSGI bundle, to get data from service-componenet and to response http request via spring-boot, to detect desktop app state change from service-component and  to notify web client the state change  via RabbitMQ

Comment: There is no good way to integrate spring boot and OSGi. I suggest to rely on OSGi solutions for http. There is the http whiteboard spec and the jax-rs whiteboard spec. So if you want to offer or call a rest service this can be done in a pure OSGi bundle. Rabbit mq is also OSGi ready. So my suggestion is to use declarative services as dependency injection and the above spec impls and rabbitmq driver for the communication.

Comment: the legacy app runs with java7; rabbitmq for OSGI depends on java8; http for OSGI needs more coding compared with spring-boot.